# What factors effect the energy change in a reaction?

Tags: energy

The reaction of zinc metal and copper sulfate solution produces copper metal and zinc sulfate solution. What factors affect how much energy is given out for this reaction?

So far I have:The mass of zinc, Pressure of surrounding area, Concentration of copper sulfate, Surface area of the solid reactants (i.e zinc), Volume of copper sulfate, Light intensity, pH of the copper sulfate.

If you can think of anymore or provide a link where I can find the information it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Some of your parameters do not affect anything, and some affect only the speed of reaction, but not its energy output.

Comment: Do you have an  idea on what does affect energy change?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of enthalpy, $\ce{\Delta H}$, in chemical reactions, it's always change in bonds. By definition, chemical reactions are those which alter bonds between atoms and molecules, and breaking old bonds/forming new bonds involves energy. For example, combustion reactions give off heat because they form products with strong bonds (the $\ce{C=O}$ double bond, for example; strong bonds release a lot of energy and are thus more stable).

In reality, the work that can be done by a chemical reaction $\ce{\Delta G}$ (Gibbs Free Energy) also relates to a change in the entropy of the system. For example, if a reaction produced a lot of gas, the gas could expand and also do work, in addition to the energy calculated from enthalpy.